# How to not use "just-computed" values in order to compute "next" values in plyr/ddply

Tags: r, plyr

In the following code on ddply:

```
ddply(df, .(groupA), summarise, x=sum(x)/sum(a), y=sum(x)/sum(b))
```

when you run the above function to compute `y` value by `sum(x)/sum(b)`, you wouldn't get what you intend to get and instead get `sum(sum(x)/sum(a))/sum(b)`, since `x` is overwritten in the `x=sum(x)/sum(a)` and the original df's `x` is no more available.

So how to NOT use the newly-calculated `x` values and instead use the original df's `x`? I remember this functionality was not implemented previously and added at some point in 2011 or 2012. However, I didn't remember when its feature was added nor find the relevant documentation, so could anyone help me here? I think there are some ways to resolve the issue if I remember it correctly...

Thanks.

[update]

SimonO101, for example, these two code return different results:

```
ddply(mtcars,.(cyl),summarise,x=mean(hp/wt))
ddply(mtcars,.(cyl),summarise,hp=mean(hp),wt=mean(wt),x=mean(hp/wt))
```

, since the second function takes the values of `hp` and `wt` from the just-calculated `mean(hp)` and `mean(wt)`, not the original df's `hp` and `wt`. So I'd like to know how to avoid the name conflict without avoiding naming those columns the same name as the original column.

Comment: It would help MASSIVELY to give a reproducible example, using a built-in dataset, perhaps `data( mtcars )` ?

Comment: Personally, I probably wouldn't waste much time trying to be clever here, I'd just use some other name besides `x`, say `x1`. And then if I _really_ need that column to be called `x`, I'd just rename it on the next line.

Comment: SimonO101, updated. joran, that's exactly the approach that I've used since the feature was added at some time in the past. I just want to write it in one line if it's feasible.

Comment: I suspect you can't; I think, as you noted, this behavior was switched at some point, so that now it's more like `mutate`. My guess is that the hassle with the names was considered less important than the gain of being able to refer to newly created variables.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution that works just fine in your example (but might not always) is to switch the order of the statements:

```
library(plyr)
d1 <- ddply(mtcars,.(cyl),summarise,
        x=mean(hp/wt),  ## do this first!
        hp=mean(hp),
        wt=mean(wt))
## check
d1[d1$cyl=="4","x"] == with(subset(mtcars,cyl==4),mean(hp/wt))
```

I usually leave myself a little note like the comment above so that I don't forget and switch the order (and confuse the hell out of myself) at some point in the future.

http://r4stats.com/2013/01/22/comparing-tranformation-styles/ is a useful discussion.